# How to convert this T-SQL query to LINQ syntax?

Tags: linq, t-sql

I´m trying to write below T-SQL query in LINQ. But I can´t figure out the syntax. Please help me out here.

```
SELECT
    MONTH( O.Date) AS Month,
    SUM( P.Price * PO.Quantity ) AS OrderSumPerMonth 
FROM
    Products P
    INNER JOIN ProductOrders PO ON P.ProductId = PO.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON PO.OrderId = O.OrderId
GROUP BY
    MONTH( O.Date );
```

Comment: There might be a bug in your original SQL query: you group only by the month-number, ignoring the year, so months from different years will be combined. Is this intentional?

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = dbContext.ProductOrders
    .GroupBy( po => new { po.Order.Date.Year, po.Order.Date.Month } )
    .Select( grp => new
    {
        grp.Key,
        OrderSumPerMonth = grp.Sum( po => po.Product.Price * po.Quantity )
    } );

foreach(var row in query) {
    WriteLine( "{0}/{1} - {2:C}", row.Key.Year, row.Key.Month, row.OrderSumPerMonth );
}
```